# How do I search both stackoverflow.com and programmers.stackexchange.com with Google site option?

Tags: support, search

Because these two sites don't share domain name I cannot use Google site:stackoverflow.com option narrow the search. Is there a mirror of stackoverflow under stackexchange domain so I can use the site option or some other hack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for this in a regular Google search is to combine the `site:` specifiers with an `OR` operator. So, your query could look like this:

```
"code review" site:stackoverflow.com OR site:programmers.stackexchange.com
```

That returns the results you're looking for.

Alternatively, you could create a [custom search engine](http://www.google.com/support/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70308), which would make this even easier to access, and infinitely more customizable with labels, filters, etc.

I banged [this one](http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=004235170926942036810:2zhebbhwbl8) out real quickly; should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Bah.  Beat me again by a minute.  I was googling [Spolsky site:programmers.stackexchange.com OR site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=subdomains+sites+google+searching&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=Xf1&tbo=1&channel=fs&source=hp&q=Spolsky+site:programmers.stackexchange.com+OR+site%3Astackoverflow.com&pbx=1&oq=Spolsky+site:programmers.stackexchange.com+OR+site%3Astackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=8653l11087l10l11398l8l7l0l0l0l1l202l775l3.3.1l7l0&tbo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c8c7245972dc282d&biw=1432&bih=726).